# trying to work out coords based collision

Tags: java, collision-detection

In this game I'm working on, both player and enemies are represented by 32x32 sprites(not using bounding boxes).

I'm trying to make a system where if the x and y coordinates of the player and enemies is less than 32, which would mean they're basically on top of eachother, to print out a message.

I store the enemies in a LinkedList. This is my collision detection code:

```
for (Entity entity : entities) {
            int deathByX = Math.abs(entity.getX() - player.getX());
            int deathByY = Math.abs(entity.getY() - player.getY());
            if (deathByX < 32 && deathByY < 32) {
                System.out.println("You died");
            }
        }
```

But as of right now, it does nothing, even if my player is right on top of my enemy. What could I do to make this code work?

Comment: So I assume this code *does not* work? How does this "not working" manifest? What do you expect this code to do and what does it do instead? Does it create a build error? Does it throw an exception? Does it run but do something weird?

Comment: Sorry, I was not specific. I'm trying to make a system where if the x and y coordinates of the player and enemies is less than 32, which would mean they're basically on top of eachother, to print out that message( later to be replaced with something more exciting).

Comment: As of right now, it does nothing.

Comment: It doesn't print "You died" even when you're right on top of the enemy?

Comment: @immibis no, it does not.

Comment: I'm putting this question on hold for the moment. As Philipp describes in the answer below, there's not enough information in the question to reproduce the issue and diagnose its cause. Try to create a minimal complete verifiable example of the issue, and add it to your question, then we can re-open it for additional answers.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your code and I could not find any obvious mistake. It seems to me as if it should do what you want it to do. But as Donald Knuth once said:

> Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it.

Nevertheless, I believe that the most likely reason why this code does not work is outside of the code snippet you posted. Some possible reasons could be:

- This code section is in some method which doesn't get executed every tick
- The entity you see on the screen isn't actually in the `entities` list.
- The coordinates provided by `getX` / `getY` are not actually pixel-coordinates but use some other unit of measurement
- player and entity don't actually use the same coordinate system

If this were my project, then I would analyze the problem by running the game in the Java debugger. If you haven't concerned yourself yet with how the debugger of your development environment works, then you should do so. It is an invaluable tool for troubleshooting bugs in your programs.

I would move the player to intersect an enemy and then set a debugger breakpoint in front of that for-loop. When the breakpoint gets triggered, then I just eliminated the first point. I can then eliminate the second right away by checking the content of the entities array in the debugger's local variables window and see if I find the enemy I collided with. When it is there, then I would set a second, conditional breakpoint within the loop which triggers when `entity` is equal to the entity I am looking for and continue execution. When the break-point gets triggered, then I would keep executing step-by-step to check the return values of getX and getY of both the player and the entity, check if `Math.abs` does what I believe it should do, and why the if-statement doesn't get triggered.